# HighCharts Highstock daily vertical grid lines showing on weekend

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need to display a vertical grid line for each data point (day) in my chart. In the following jsfiddle, you can see a vertical grid line for each day, but the problem is lines are showing for weekends/holidays (even though there is not data for those days, and I'm using an ordinal x-axis).  Does anyone know how to disable the grid lines for non-trading days (weekends/holidays)?

http://jsfiddle.net/kngz3exf/4/

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    global: {
        useUTC: true
    }
});
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

        rangeSelector: {
            enabled: false
        },

        yAxis: {
            gridLineWidth: 0
        },

        xAxis: {
            gridLineColor: '#000000',
            gridLineWidth: 1,
            lineColor: '#000000',
            tickColor: '#000000',
            minorGridLineColor: '#000000',
            minorGridLineWidth: 1,
            minorTickColor: '#000000',
            ordinal: true,
            tickInterval: 86400000,
            minorTickInterval: 86400000
        },

        series: [{
            data:[
                [Date.UTC(2014,11,1), -0.4818850000000001],
                [Date.UTC(2014,11,2), -0.40866199999999997],
                [Date.UTC(2014,11,3), 0.20889499999999994],
                [Date.UTC(2014,11,4), -0.623542],
                [Date.UTC(2014,11,5), -0.060399999999999995],
                [Date.UTC(2014,11,8), -0.56108],
                [Date.UTC(2014,11,9), 0.30852700000000005],
                [Date.UTC(2014,11,10), -0.4492829999999999],
                [Date.UTC(2014,11,11), -0.275211],
                [Date.UTC(2014,11,12), 0.013063999999999965],
                [Date.UTC(2014,11,15), -0.27293900000000004],
                [Date.UTC(2014,11,16), 0.49981200000000003],
                [Date.UTC(2014,11,17), 0.2362090000000001],
                [Date.UTC(2014,11,18), 0.4464490000000003],
                [Date.UTC(2014,11,19), 1.2100639999999998],
                [Date.UTC(2014,11,22), -0.792635],
                [Date.UTC(2014,11,23), 0.14788899999999994],
                [Date.UTC(2014,11,24), 0.011684],
                [Date.UTC(2014,11,26), 0.08526699999999998],
                [Date.UTC(2014,11,29), -0.12494599999999997],
                [Date.UTC(2014,11,30), -0.06489100000000003],
                [Date.UTC(2014,11,31), 0.279632]
            ]
        }]
    });
});
```

[From Sebastian's fiddle update](http://jsfiddle.net/kngz3exf/5/)
[image: fiddle]

[image: closeup]

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap getMinorTick function and add condition to check if day is in the weekend.

Wrapper:

```
    (function (HC) {
    HC.wrap(HC.Axis.prototype, 'getMinorTickPositions', function (proceed, points) {
        var axis = this,
            options = axis.options,
            tickPositions = axis.tickPositions,
            minorTickInterval = axis.minorTickInterval,
            minorTickPositions = [],
            pos,
            i,
            len;

        if (axis.isLog) {
            len = tickPositions.length;
            for (i = 1; i < len; i++) {
                minorTickPositions = minorTickPositions.concat(
                axis.getLogTickPositions(minorTickInterval, tickPositions[i - 1], tickPositions[i], true));
            }
        } else if (axis.isDatetimeAxis && options.minorTickInterval === 'auto') { // #1314
            minorTickPositions = minorTickPositions.concat(
            axis.getTimeTicks(
            axis.normalizeTimeTickInterval(minorTickInterval),
            axis.min,
            axis.max,
            options.startOfWeek));
            if (minorTickPositions[0] < axis.min) {
                minorTickPositions.shift();
            }
        } else {
            var today = 0;

            for (pos = axis.min + (tickPositions[0] - axis.min) % minorTickInterval; pos <= axis.max; pos += minorTickInterval) {
                today = new Date(pos)
                if(today.getDay() != 6 && today.getDay() != 0) {
                minorTickPositions.push(pos);

                }        
            }
        }
        return minorTickPositions;
    });
}(Highcharts));
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/kngz3exf/5/

Comment: Does the jsfiddle update you provide solve the issue, or was it more of an idea to get me started?  I ask because when I look at your jsfiddle the errant vertical grid lines still exist.

Comment: In my fiddle gridlines for saturday/sunday are not printed. But for christmas extist.

Comment: When looking at your fiddle - for example, Fri Dec 5 - Mon Dec 8 - I see a vertical line on Fri the 5th, a vertical line for Sat the 6th, a vertical line on Sun the 7th, and Mon the 8th is missing a vertical line.

Comment: For me it looks like ok, so which widht you have?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by width.  My screen size?  I've added an image of your fiddle to illustrate my comments.

Comment: My resolution is 1920 x 1200

Comment: The problem is that you have oridnal as true, so ticks are not in the regular position. So you can ordinal as false and modify my code to remove some lines.